# Let $H$ be a subgroup of $G$. Show that if $G/H$ is abelian, then $ghg^{-1}h^{-1}$ is in $H$ for all $g, h$ in $G$.

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $H$ be a subgroup of $G$. Show that if $G/H$ is abelian, then $ghg^{-1}h^{-1}$ is in $H$ for all $g, h$ in $G$..

I know if $G/H$ is abelian, $(g_1H)(g_2H)=(g_2H)(g_1H)$. But I don't know how to approach from here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have it. So what is $(g_1g_2g_1^{-1}g_2^{-1})H$? (P.S. Probably it's better not to use the letter $h$ for an element of $G$; it suggests an element of $H$. So I think your switching to $g_1$ and $g_2$ was preferable.)

Comment: Sorry I am still confused, why (g1g2g1−1g2−1)H can prove the statement?

Comment: If that element of $G/H$ equals $eH$, then $g_1g_2g_1^{-1}g_2^{-1}\in H$.